# Using jQuery, focusing on input field in iOS brings up the keyboard but not the cursor. How do I get around this?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad

I created a handler for blur on an input. After calling this blur function, I then call focus on the input field:

```
$input.focus();
```

As you can see, it is very simple. However, the issue is that keyboard comes up on the iPad, but the cursor does not show up. If I start typing, then the cursor comes up.

So how do I make the cursor come up before the user starts typing?

Comment: Try wrapping that in a click event

Comment: @JoshSpears, I tried doing that, and unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Comment: @gjvatsalya Did you find a solution?

Comment: @RevanthKausikan unfortunately, I do not remember since it was so long ago.